# finding the max lenth of string values in a spark dataframe string column?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

How can i find the maximum length of string in a spark dataframe column ?
I tried

```
 val maxLentgh: Int = df.agg(max(length(col(x.name))).first()
```

i also tried this but i doubt it would be performent.

```
val  maxLength = df.select(colName).collect().map(_(0)).toList.map(x=>x.toString.length).max
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **length** to find the string length and then use **rank** to find the order and align them in desc order to get the max length:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(("abc"), ("abcdef")).toDF("str")    

val win=Window.orderBy(length(col("str")).desc)

val finalDf = df
.withColumn("len", length(col("str")))
.withColumn("rank",  row_number().over(win))

finalDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+---+----+
|    str|len|rank|
+-------+---+----+
| abcdef|  6|   1|
|    abc|  3|   2|
+-------+---+----+
```

and then:

```
val maxLen = finalDf.collect()(0)(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
```